# How do I overload operators for some specific data types?

Tags: c++

Consider this code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    template <typename T>
    foo& operator<< (const T& var) {
        cout << var;
        return *this;
    }
} bar;

int main() {
    bar << 1 << '\n';
    bar << 1.2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I want to overload `<<` operator only for integer data types. (`int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`)
How can I do that?

Comment: Also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SFINAE to ensure that `T` is an integral type:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, foo&> 
operator<< (const T& var) {
    cout << var;
    return *this;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
foo& operator<< (const T& var) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integral type"); 
    cout << var;
    return *this;
}
```

Note that you should *not* `#include` anything from the `bits` folder, that's non-portable.

---

If you want separate overloads for integral and floating point types, you can make two overloads and select with SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, foo&>
operator<< (const T& var) {
    cout << "int " << var;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, foo&>
operator<< (const T& var) {
    cout << "float " << var;
    return *this;
}
```

---

When we get Concepts you'll be able to write something like this:

```
template <Integral T>
//        ^^^^^^^^ Integral rather than typename
foo& operator<< (const T& var) {
    cout << var;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use `bits` for competitive programming to avoid writing lots of headers.

Comment: how can I overload differently for integral types and float types?